# get the first n characters of getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

I have a case compare date, hour of datetime column and current date,hour

```
select * from tbl where  LEFT(EVENT_TIME_column,13) !=LEFT(GETDATE(),13)
```

`EVENT_TIME_column` format is `'2019-08-15 12:32:40.0000000'`

when i perform `LEFT(GETDATE(),13)` result is '`Aug 15 2019'`

can you suggest how to get `GETDate()` in `'2019-08-15 12'` (date and hour)

Comment: SQL tag on this website is not meant to indicate SQL Server (MSSQL).. If you hold (hover) mouse on top of the tag you can read the meaning of the tag(s)

Comment: *"`EVENT_TIME_column` format is `'2019-08-15 12:32:40.0000000' `"* No it isn't. Date and Time datatypes are stored **without** a format, they are stored as a binary value. The format is purely determined by the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the **format** `yyyy-MM-dd hh` then can do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(13),GETDATE(),120);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=431fc598288a852694e21bdea076fce5)

You can find a full list of all the style codes for `CONVERT` in the documentation: [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)

However, it looks like you want to check if the date is within the current hour. That would be:

```
WHERE EVENT_TIME_column >= DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0,GETDATE()),0)
  AND EVENT_TIME_column < DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0,GETDATE())+1, 0)
```

This explicitly avoids any functions on the column `EVENT_TIME_column`; which would make the query non-SARGable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string functions on date/time values!  There are perfectly good built-in functions:

```
where convert(date, event_time_column) = convert(date, getdate()) and
      datepart(hour, event_time_column) = datepart(hour, getdate())
```

If you don't care about index usage, then use `datediff()`:

```
where datediff(hour, event_time_column, getdate()) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this with 2 separate comparison as below. This is for checking Date and Hour part is same as date and hour part if GETDATE() or not.

```
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIME_column AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND DATEPART(HH,EVENT_TIME_column) =  DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())
```

To check NOT EQUAL TO, Just replace = sign with != sign.

In addition, If I guess correct you are only trying to avoid records from running hour of to date. If this is the case, you can also filter your data with below logic-

```
WHERE EVENT_TIME_column < DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, getdate()), 0)
```